# Google App Engine composer dependencies do not update

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, composer-php, google-app-engine-php

I'm running my PHP application on Google Cloud App Engine Standard. After I deployed a new version of my app with a new composer package, I see that this new package was not installed during the deployment.

I deploy my app with `gcloud app deploy`. In the Cloud Console Debug tool, I can't find the package in the `vendor` folder. The package is successfully installed locally.

Is there a trick to update composer packages?

Comment: Please specify what package are you trying to import? Which version of PHP are you using? Could you provide a code snippet of your composer file?

Comment: According to Google Cloud Platform documentation on [**Specifying Dependencies**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/specifying-dependencies) for PHP,
**composer** runs automatically when you deploy a new version of your application.

You can also try adding `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` to the top of your PHP script to require the **autoload.php** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. Turns out this only works for '2nd generation run times'. In other words, your application will need to be PHP7.3. php5 applications will not process composer files.